# Python regex OR expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a file named `Document.pdf` and sometimes it is called `Document-12345678.pdf` where `-12345678` is a random number.

I want to check a file is downloaded in folder. When the file is not finished it display `Document.pdf.fkasfmq` or `Document-12345678.pdf.fkasfmq` where `.fkasfmq` is a random hash from the downloader and I don't want it to match.

I try make a regex like `r'Document(?:[\-0-9]+).pdf'` and test it with either `Document.pdf` or `Document-12345678.pdf` it will always return false.

From my understanding `(?:[\-0-9]+)` means it can be or not in the set that matches any hyphen and any numbers before `.pdf`, is that correct? I am very very rusty with regex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mark it as optional with the `"?"` symbol. Otherwise, you are requiring that the name should have the numbers and/or digits part.

```
r'Document(?:[\-0-9]+)?\.pdf'
```

Or as @anubhava pointed out in the comments, it can be simplified to:

```
r'Document[\-0-9]*\.pdf'
```

- This way, it will also match e.g. `"Document.pdf"`

Also, you should consider putting the mark `"$"` to signify end of string so that it doesn't match e.g. `"Document.pdf.fkasfmq"`

```
r'^Document(?:[\-0-9]+)?\.pdf$'
```

Or

```
r'^Document[\-0-9]*\.pdf$'
```

Comment: Yup your answer is correct `pattern = re.compile(r'^Document(?:[\-0-9]+)?.pdf$')` and `bool(pattern.match('Document.pdf'))` , `bool(pattern.match('Document-12345678.pdf'))` returns `True` whilst `bool(pattern.match('Document-12345678.pdf.fkasfmq'))` returns `False` thankyou sir

Comment: Glad it helped you :) My answer was built on top of the original regex stated in the question. I updated it to a simplified version as pointed out by @anubhava.

Answer (score 2):

The parentheses only perform grouping, not optionality. If you want to make the expression optional, the `?` quantifier does that (and actually the parentheses are unnecessary, as the character class is a single expression). Though as @anubhava notes in a comment, you might as well use the `*` quantifier then.

```
r'Document[-0-9]*\.pdf'
```

Notice also the backslash to match a literal dot; an unescaped `.` matches any character (other than newline). Inside a character class, an initial or final hyphen does not need to be backslash-escaped.

On the other hand, perhaps prefer a more precise expression:

```
r'^Document(-\d)?\.pdf$'
```

which says, opionally, a hyphen followed by numbers, and nothing before or after.

Comment: So that means I don't need `?` at all?

Comment: Indeed, `*` means "zero or more of the previous" which is both simpler and more direct than "an optional group (i.e. zero or one) of one or more of the previous expression".

Comment: This would also work (note that it might also only match hyphens)

Comment: Updated with a more precise alternative.

Comment: Including Niel Godfrey Ponciano answer, we also want end of string so the full answer is `r'Document(-\d)?\.pdf$'`

Comment: You want a leading anchor as well then (or not, if you use `re.match`, but you don't disclose this in the question). Updated.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use (\d{8}) to see if there's a document there with 8 digits in the filename.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it can be any length of digits

Comment: Ok, what about (pdf.\w[a-z]) to check if .pdf is followed by .jeofjaf for example? if it returns false then the file must be completed, right?

Comment: That answer does not provide a solution to this question. You can leave a comment below to the author's post if you need more clarification.